# I don't have a volume taskbar icon&keyboard shortcuts not doing anything

Tags: keyboard, xfce, volume-control

- I don't have a volume shortcut to my taskbar.
- When I use my Logitech's VOL+ and VOL- keys, I see the transparent popup icon but the actual volume is not changing.

I tried experimenting with PulseAudio but I couldn't get it to show a shortcut icon on my taskbar.

Here's my UNAME:

```
Linux g-on-linux 3.5.0-25-generic #39-Ubuntu SMP Mon Feb 25 18:26:58 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

XUbuntu 12.10
XFCE4.10
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you recently upgrade your Ubuntu? Try this it might help. Use Alt+F2 to open the Run Application app, paste gnome-volume-control-applet into the text field, and click the Run button (you can also enter the command into a terminal, but the button will disappear if you close the terminal). To get it to start automatically from the next reboot, go to System > Preferences > Startup Applications and add it as a new entry with a name like Volume Button.

Comment: I don't have this installed; It's a fresh Xubuntu install, no upgrades.. It was like that since the beginning.. (it's XFCE4 so I don't have the Gnome stuff..)

Comment: try this http://askubuntu.com/questions/240623/missing-volume-app-from-notification-area-in-xubuntu-12-10-panel