# No sound settings available in the settings manager window

Tags: xubuntu, pulseaudio, indicator-sound

Last night I decided to upgrade my system to the latest version of Xubuntu, 13.10. The process went fine, but now I'm facing this strange issue. There is no sound settings available in the settings manager window and the volume indicator looks like when the volume is muted, clicking the indicator being broken as well. [The indicator looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VMGEI.png):

[image]

I tried to do a `alsa force-reload` followed by a restart of the computer, but didn't help. Any thoughts ?

l.e. After some digging I found out that the volume control exists, so this must be a **volume indicator issue**.

Comment: Unless there is a permanent fix and the indicator-sound package happens to be re-released, you will have to do this manual patch again. On message #69 in the bug report (described above by Elfy), there is a tar.gz archive containing automation for re-applying that patch. Anyone having trouble with the blueman package? The same bug report has a patch for that too. Hopefully, both of these two irritants will be resolved permanently soon by the very busy package owners. Please have patience.

Comment: Bug was fixed in latest release of Xubuntu. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-sound-gtk2/+bug/1208204

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The release notes for Xubuntu 13.10 include this problem as one of the known issues for that release. (See link to release notes below.)
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SaucySalamander/ReleaseNotes/Xubuntu

This problem has been fixed in the current development release and a stable release update is [currently pending](http://people.canonical.com/~ubuntu-archive/pending-sru.html) to fix [this issue in 13.10](http://pad.lv/1208204)

Any prior work-arounds were deemed dangerous to system stability in the [Xubuntu team meeting on 2013-12-05](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Xubuntu/Meetings/Archive/Minutes/2013-12-05). Users were strongly advised from that point forward to not implement them in any manner.

This has now been released to `saucy-updates` and once a system is updated after install no longer an issue.

Comment: thanks, that did the trick. the indicator is back :) though, I'm surprised that the release was left with this kind of bugs.

Comment: you'd not be surprised if you knew how many people there are in the team and how many can actually deal with bugs - come and help http://xubuntu.org/contribute/

Comment: This works also without reboot, logging out and in again suffices

Comment: Instead of logging out then back in, you can kill the `indicator-sound-service` process and then restart the panel using `xfce4-panel -r`

Comment: You know that you can click the edit button and edit the answer - that's the point of AU :)