# nm-applett and sound-indicator in systray gone and sound not working after update 13.10

Tags: upgrade, sound, network-manager, system-tray

After upgrading my Xubuntu 13.04 to 13.10 I have some problems:

- the NetworkManager is not in the taskbar, I think that is the notifications-applet (german: "Nachrichtenanzeige")
- the sound-indicator-applett in the systray is gone
- I have no sound, that means, I still have sound if I start VLC with

  sudo mpg123 test.mp3

So it seems there is a right problem

**the systray problem:**

The systray's notifications-applet is usually looking like this:

[image]
or this:

[image]

it is not working anymore. No audio-settings and no network-manager in the taskbar in XFCE: there is just one small box with nothing in it.

When I install `stalonetray`, there I see the status of wicd and all the other statuses, so the systray seems to be broken.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Volume indicator issue after xubuntu 13.10 upgrade](http://askubuntu.com/questions/360806/volume-indicator-issue-after-xubuntu-13-10-upgrade)

Comment: I answerd it below already

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## sound

add yourself to the group `audio` with

```
adduser yourself audio
```

then you can play sounds again as yourself.

## sound-indicator

> see: [No sound settings available in the settings manager window](https://askubuntu.com/questions/360806/volume-indicator-issue-after-xubuntu-13-10-upgrade)

This is noted on the release notes for Xubuntu 13.10 and is a known issue.

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SaucySalamander/ReleaseNotes/Xubuntu

It is this bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-sound/+bug/1208204

You can use the workround:

Edit the service file

```
gksu mousepad /usr/share/dbus-1/services/indicator-sound.service
```

It will look like

```
[D-BUS Service] Name=com.canonical.indicator.sound
Exec=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/indicator-sound/indicator-sound-service
```

Comment out the last line and enter a new one, should look like

```
[D-BUS Service] Name=com.canonical.indicator.sound
#Exec=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/indicator-sound/indicator-sound-service
Exec=/usr/lib/indicator-sound-gtk2/indicator-sound-service
```

Save that and log out an in again

## network-manager

no solution yet

Answer (score -1):

I installed kubuntu-desktop with wicd and removed network-manager.

There was only one thing I had to do:
the file resolv.conf was a relative link to ../run/resolvconf/resolv.conf

I changed that symlink to be absolute and the daemon now runs

```
etc/resolv.conf -> /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf
```

Now wicd works instead of network-manager and everything looks fine in KDE ;)

(but this is no solution for Xubuntu)