# Problem with nm-applet in Xubuntu 13.10: nm-applet: Failed to register as an agent: (32) Session not found

Tags: xubuntu, 13.10, network-manager

I recently upgraded to Xubuntu 13.10
I can still use the NetworkManager but the indicator icon is gone after the upgrade

If I start it manually, I get this error:

```
** (nm-applet:5632): WARNING **: Could not initialize NMClient /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager: Rejected send message, 3 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.54" (uid=1000 pid=5632 comm="nm-applet ") interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" member="GetAll" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager" (uid=0 pid=930 comm="NetworkManager ")
** Message: applet now removed from the notification area

** (nm-applet:5632): WARNING **: Failed to register as an agent: (32) Session not found
```

How can I get the nm-applet back?

I had another problem after update with the sound-indicator, but solved it like this: https://askubuntu.com/a/369093/34298

---

If I try

```
dbus-launch nm-applet --sm-launch &
```

I get the error

```
** (nm-applet:12425): WARNING **: Could not initialize NMClient /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager: The name org.freedesktop.NetworkManager was not provided by any .service files
** Message: applet now removed from the notification area

** (nm-applet:12425): WARNING **: Failed to register as an agent: (2) The name  org.freedesktop.NetworkManager was not provided by any .service files
** Message: using fallback from indicator to GtkStatusIcon
```

Answer (score 1):

You can install `wicd` instead:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install wicd wicd-gtk
apt-get remove network-manager
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `dbus-launch nm-applet --sm-launch &`

Comment: This doesen't solve the problem, I updated my question with the error