# Xubuntu 13.10 volume panel item always shows "muted"

Tags: sound, xubuntu, volume-control, xfce-panel

When I use the Fn keys for volume (up, down, mute), I get a nice notification of the current volume, and everything works.

However, the panel item for volume, between battery and network, always shows the sound as muted. (Loudspeaker with two dashes.) When I click onto it, I don't get a volume slider, either. What's the matter here?

Comment: Googling yielded this bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-sound/+bug/1208204

Comment: Also this thread exists:

http://askubuntu.com/questions/360806/volume-indicator-issue-after-xubuntu-13-10-upgrade

Sorry for the duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

Googling yielded this bug report:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-sound/+bug/1208204

They propose two workarounds:

1) Downgrading to install indicator-sound_12.10.2daily13.04.12-0ubuntu1_amd64 from Rapid, and

2) Restarting the thingy with killall indicator-sound-service;/usr/lib/indicator-sound-gtk2/indicator-sound-service

I have tried 2), and that works. Found the bug report through this thread, exactly the same problem:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2179665

(Off-topic, but I personally think it's a shame to mark this bug "Low Priority". Users care about things like that.)

Comment: If this solutoin solves your question, feel free to `accept` your own answer.